# Getting cross device notification dismissal working with Device Group Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In the docs for Device Group Messaging it says that deleting a notification on one device deletes it on all the others.
How do I implement this? I don't see any way to map a GCM push to a notification.

"If a message has been handled on one device, the GCM message on the other devices are dismissed. For example, if a user has handled a calendar notification on a watch the notification will go away on the user's phone and tablet."

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications

Comment: If you create a device group, it will handle the dismissal for all your devices. To create a device group, send a POST request that provides a name for the group, and a list of registration tokens for the devices. GCM returns a new `notification_key` that represents the device group. You can see [this page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#creating_a_device_group) for more details.

Comment: The documentation seems to imply this should happen automatically, but merely creating a notification_key is not enough to get the automatic dismissal, at least in my example

Comment: @EugeneStyer You have to send an upstream message to the device group and handle the message on each of the user's devices to be able to manually dismiss the notification on each device?

Comment: The problem is that if the user dismisses the notification without opening it, GcmListenerService never lets me know that the notification ever existed, so I never have the chance to send the upstream message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the lead of Firebase Cloud Messaging (the successor to GCM) and they said that this has not been implemented yet, and that the docs were incorrect when I posted this.